# Determine if the set of all $f \in C(\mathbb{R})$ such that $f(1/2)$ is a rational number is a subspace of $C(\mathbb{R})$

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis

Let $C(\mathbb{R})$ denote the vector space over $\mathbb{R}$ of all continuous functions on $\mathbb{R}$. Determine if the set of all $f \in C(\mathbb{R})$ such that $f(1/2)$ is a rational number is a subspace of $C(\mathbb{R})$

I know that in order to prove that a set is a subspace or not I have to prove it is closed under vector addition and scalar multiplication and it has to contain the zero vector. But I don't know what to add and multiply.

Comment: The vectors are the functions themselves, e.g., the zero vector is the zero function. *Hint:* the product of a rational and an irrational number is irrational

Comment: The operations on $C(\mathbb{R})$ are defined pointwise, that is, $(f+g)(x)=f(x)+g(x)$, $(\alpha \cdot g)(x)=\alpha \cdot g(x)$, etc.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

The "vectors" in $C(\mathbb{R})$ are continuous functions. So in order to check closure under addition you need to start with two functions $f, g \in S$, where $S=\left\{f \in C(\mathbb{R}) \, | \, f\left(\frac{1}{2}\right) \in \mathbb{Q}\right\}$ and then determine if the sum function $f+g \in S$. Let us call $h=f+g$. Since sum of two continuous functions is continuous so $h$ is continuous. Moreover 
$$h\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)=f\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)+g\left(\frac{1}{2}\right) \in \mathbb{Q}.$$ 
Here we use the fact that sum of two rationals is rational (i.e. $\mathbb{Q}$ is closed under addition.)

Now try the rest.